# Validation and Post with list of models inside a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having a hard time figuring out how I would validate/submit a list of models inside my main model.  For Example:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult submitData(MyModel model){
   ...submit data...
}
```

Model:

```
public class MyModel{
    [Required]
    public string Title{get;set;}
    ...
    [Required]
    IList<SubModel> SubModels{getset;}
}
public class SubModel{
    [Required]
    public string Title {get;set;}
}
```

View:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("submitData", "Home", FormMethod.Post){
   @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Title);
   ... Code for submodels
}
```

the sub models should be able to be added on the fly, which i have set in javascript, but the submodels should be an arbitrary amount depending on how many the user wants to add.  How can i make it so my validation for the submodels work and when i submit the post, everything fits neatly into the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you using non-sequential indexes when naming your input fields. Steven Sanderson has an [`excellent article`](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) on this subject illustrating a step-by-step example on how to achieve that. It uses a custom `Html.BeginCollectionItem` helper which will take care to generate proper names for the input fields of the collection property using Guids and thus respect the [`naming convention`](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) used by the default model binder.

Steven Sanderson also wrote [`another article`](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/) which illustrates how you could achieve the same using pure client side templating and not relying on AJAX calls to add new items.

But remember that no matter what you do, once you submit the form, the naming convention should be respected if you want the default model binder to be able to properly bind the collection property on your view model.